# Allowing users to traverse document librarys\sub sites

Tags: document-library, permissions, access-rights

As the subject reads, Ive added a user to a SharePoint group which has contribute rights to a subsite. What I would like to do is allow that user to traverse the additional sites\document library's but only view whats been shared with them. If I go to the site above and check permissions for this user it says they have none - any ideas please?

Thanks as always

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you'll need to set unique permissions on the items being shared unless you want to create folders, which also sucks.

Answer (score 0):

You have given access to the subsite (Which has unique permissions) and the access is not provided in top site. So that you are getting none for permissions, when you are checking on top site.

Give the access to top-level site and also provide access to unique permission assigned sites. So that user can traverse to all subsites.

Comment: So to confirm giving access to the top site shouldn't give the user access to files within the top site (and subsequent sites) unless someone gives the user explicit rights - is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

On a top level site, if you add a user to a SharePoint group that has read access to the top level site, that user will have read access to any content on the site that does not have unique permissions, and any sub site in the collection that uses the SharePoint group.

It sounds as if you are going to have to identify each site, and each list and library with unique permissions, the user needs to access, and add the user to the groups that provision permmissions for those content areas.